# Getting "Uncaught reflect-metadata shim" when trying to upgrade my angular project to Webpack 2

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I have an Webpack 1 project which is working fine. I want to upgrade to Webpack 2.x so I change the following in my package.json from

`"webpack": "^1.13.3",
"webpack-merge": "^2.0.0"`

To

`"webpack": "^2",
"webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"`

And I update my webpack files [per this link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/). Everything transpiles fine and I get the artifacts I expect. My pollyfills.ts looks like this...

```
...
import 'reflect-metadata'
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
...
```

Also I tried adding the following to my main file

`import 'reflect-metadata'`

But when I try to run I get the following error `Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`. I am using....

```
"@angular/common": "^2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.4.1",
"@angular/core": "^2.4.1",
```

Can someone help me with what I am missing? If I revert to the older webpack it works fine.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS-Code and Angular CLI.
And today I had exactly the same error in my console.

In my case, I just had to restart VS-Code editor. 
After starting the editor I run "**ng serve**" in the project folder and everything was working as expected, without any error.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think restarting the editor solves the problem. In my case I just restarted the cli (`ng serve` command)

Answer (score 1):

My answer apparently was similar to others. Before this my Webpack config looked like this...

```
entry: {
  polyfills: './conf/polyfills',
  vendor: './conf/deps',
  app: './src/ng2/main',
},
```

You apparently can not do this anymore (can someone find proof?). Probably thanks to some sort of isolation that Webpack 2 enforces. So I changed this to...

```
entry: {
  app: './src/ng2/main'
},
```

And at the top of my `main.ts` I added the following (after in my case also moving the files)...

```
import './polyfills'
import './deps'
```

Now it seems to work

Comment: Also this seems to mess up my karma conf so a better solution will be accepted.